PostgreSQL merge several json list
I read a lot about json combine methods but not found my way.
Have this kind of query
WITH
  products AS (
      SELECT * FROM configured_products() p
      WHERE p.is_active
  ),
  products_countries as (
      SELECT countries FROM products
      WHERE products.group_ids @> to_jsonb(121) -- test purpose
      GROUP BY products.countries
  )

The result of SELECT * FROM products_countries is a recordset such as
countries (jsonb)
["BE"]
["FR"]
["FR", "LU"]

Now, I want to merge all these countries in one jsonb record to have something like
countries (jsonb)
["BE", "FR", "LU"]

I tried a lot of solutions such as jsonb_agg() but it returns this
SELECT jsonb_agg(r) FROM (SELECT * FROM products_countries) r
[
  {
    "available_countries": [
      "BE"
    ]
  },
  {
    "available_countries": [
      "FR"
    ]
  },
  {
    "available_countries": [
      "FR",
      "LU"
    ]
  }
]

Is there a simple way to achieve that, without custom function ?

What is the point of GROUP BY products.countries?

@Bergi because in this case one product can be returned several times with different configuration.

You'll first want to split up the arrays into their elements using jsonb_array_elements in a lateral subquery, then aggregate them back together:
SELECT jsonb_agg(DISTINCT country)
FROM configured_products() p,
     jsonb_array_elements(p.countries) AS c(country)
WHERE p.is_active
  AND p.group_ids @> to_jsonb(121)


Damned you saved my day ... So simple, so beautiful ! Thank you @Bergi

One question : What is this kind of alias As c(country) ? Works too with only AS country

The alias is naming the entire relation c (like p) and the column country; you could now refer to c.country. When there's only a single column, it doesn't make much of a difference as the one-tuple (from AS country) could also be used and would be coerced to its element (or it's automatically expanded to AS country(country), I forgot how exactly this works), but otherwise that's the difference between a record value and its fields.
